# JDK 8 support for Wildfly 8.1 OpenShift cartridge

Tags: openshift, wildfly

Still no Java 8 (JDK) support for the OpenShift Wildfly 8.1 cartridge? Is this a limitation of the SELinux gear? Or can I just create a Java 8 JDK cartridge and a modified Wildfly 8 cartridge and combine them in the same gear?

Answer (score 3):

As of june 3rd, there is JDK 8 support for wildfly.
See https://www.openshift.com/content/support-for-jdk-8#comment-39656

As can be read here: https://community.jboss.org/people/fjuma/blog/2014/06/03/wildfly-810final-on-openshift--with-jdk-8-support new wildfly instances from scratch will default to JDK 8.

Answer (score 1):

OpenShift currently does not support JDK8 yet.

Once it will be added WildFly cartridge will be updated to add support for it.

There is also running discussion about this on wildfly-dev mailing list.

for more see http://wildfly-development.1055759.n5.nabble.com/WildFly-8-1-0-CR1-on-OpenShift-tt5713989.html#none