# Openshift DIY cartridge with Jetty and JDK8

Tags: jetty, openshift, java-8

At the moment openshift has no official support of java 8.
There is only one working solution that I found: [JDK 8 support for Wildfly 8.1 OpenShift cartridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230511/jdk-8-support-for-wildfly-8-1-openshift-cartridge)
But wildfly is to heavy for my project, and a small (1Gb) gear is not enough for it. (I'm using a free plan)
So I'm trying to configure it on DIY manually using Jetty.

Maybe someone already managed to do it. If not I will share my results.

So the goal is to build (using maven) and deploy application using java 8 on openshift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this.
So I can share this scripts.
Also I wrote a manual for it.
Hope this will help someone.
https://github.com/pkolmykov/jetty-openshift-java8

Comment: Trying the same on a DIY cartridge. But exporting JAVA_HOME, PATH ... doesn't seem to make any difference. Setting JAVA_HOME manually with rhc env set works ... but not for PATH (PATH cannot be overridden)